# How to completely colorize UIPopoverPresentationController background color?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, background-color

I'm working with a Day and Night Mode for an app.
The problem is, when just setting the background color of a view AND THEN using it as "presenting as popover" there are little white artifacts (see the picture)

Is there an easy way to fix this?
Do I may have to write my own UIView?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the UIPopoverPresentationController's `backgroundColor`. If that isn't sufficient, you will have to customize your popover's [UIPopoverBackgroundView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/index.html). This gives you control of the entire popover background, including the little triangle.

Comment: Sorry, would you mind giving me a little example or guide. I didn't got the point with the popoverBackgroundViewClass. In the Interface Builder I have my UIViewController which should be displayed as Popover. I implemented a class which inherits from UIPopoverBackgroundView. In another view controller is a button which calls the popover by segue. In the "prepareForSegue" method I am settings config.popoverPresentationController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = CustomPopoverBackgroundView.self.

Kind regards

Comment: It always crashes with "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIPopoverBackgroundView contentViewInsets] must be implemented by subclassers.'".

Comment: "Sorry, would you mind giving me a little example or guide" Sure: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch09p476popovers/ch22p751popovers/MyPopoverBackgroundView.swift

Comment: Thank you. Your sample code helped very much to understand this matter.

Comment: Setting `popover.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` still didn't fix it for me. This is harder than it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to supplement matt's answer.

```
popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = myColor
```

or

```
self.navigationController?.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = myColor
```