# How to add a custom border to viewcontroller (ios)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view (UIPopoverPresentation) which functionality works fine, but I need to add a custom border.  I'm currently using a borderWidth and borderColor but I cannot seem to find a way to make a customized border, as seen in the photo below.  How do I go about creating this customized border? Make a CGRect?

What I need:

[image]

What I have:
[image]

I've attempted to add an image to the background of the popover and it resulted in this:

[image]

EDIT:  //PopOverView (presented using UIPopOverPresentation)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    self.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    self.popViewTableView.delegate = self
    self.popViewTableView.dataSource = self
    self.popViewTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    self.popViewTableView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 151.0/255.0, green: 87.0/255.0, blue: 172.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)


}


//Base View Controller.  When button is pressed, this function is called which presents the popover
func presentPopOver() {

    let contentView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popViewController") as! DeckPopViewController
    contentView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    contentView.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(deckSelectionCGRect.width, 160)

    let popoverMenuViewController = contentView.popoverPresentationController!
    popoverMenuViewController.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController.sourceView = view
    popoverMenuViewController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue:0)

    popoverMenuViewController.sourceRect = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.width/2) - (deckSelectionCGRect.width/2), 120, deckSelectionCGRect.width, deckSelectionCGRect.height)
    presentViewController(contentView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}

//ALSO:  On the third image, I placed the border imageview over the entire view controller in the storyboard, set padding to zero on all sides (autolayout).  It doesn't look good, though.
```

Comment: Your last attempt is very good. Now if the background of the view were transparent, you'd be there.

Comment: Could you please show your code? Also, I think you mean view instead of ViewController

Comment: @matt I've been trying to make the background transparent but it doesn't seem to work because it is a modally presented popoverviewcontroller, not a regular view.

Comment: @penatheboss Check my edit.

Comment: Do you understand how to take over the drawing of a popover background so you can make it transparent? See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31906110/341994

Comment: Thank you Matt for your help.  Subclassing the UIPopoverBackgroundView was what I needed to do.